# Sub item in list view doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, subitem

my code is about a listview with sub item, I fill it with array string[] but only show me the first string, someone can I help me?

```
private String[] d1 = new String[5];

private String[] d2 = new String[5];

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.listview);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    for(int i=0;i<lengh;i++){
        Map<String,Object> daat = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        daat.put("title",  d1[i]);
        daat.put("sub", d2[i]);
        data.add(daat);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[]{"title", "sub"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8hyx.jpg)

Comment: problem here `i<lengh;`. Check below answer.

Comment: I've fixed it, but the result is the same

Comment: In your image, you have several item dividers shown. Therefore it looks like your already got items in your list view but the content of the items are "". You may try in the for loop, replace d1[i] with d1[0] to see if other items can be shown. Hope that help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for(int i=0;i<d1.length;i++){
    Map<String,Object> daat = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    daat.put("title",  d1[i]);
    daat.put("sub", d2[i]);
    data.add(daat);
 }
```

hear in for loop specify which string length and try i hope it work .

Comment: Thank you!, but still showing the first string as in the image, can help me?